# Finding adjacent pairs of characters in a string using recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have to write a program that uses a recursive function to count the number of pairs of repeated characters in a string, and pairs of characters cannot overlap.

Say, for instance, I input the string "Hello, Sabeena". I need the output to be "2", one for the pair of ls and one for the pair of es.

This is what I have tried, but there is no output.

```
message = input("Enter a message:\n")
pairs = 0
k = 0

if len(message) == k:
    return("Number of pairs:",pairs)
else:
    if message[k] == message[k+1]:
        pairs = pairs + 1
        k = k+1
    else:
        k = k+1
```

Ideally, the program should look like this:

```
Enter a message:
Hello, Sabeena
Number of pairs: 2
```

Can anybody suggest where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You should at least have a loop.

Comment: That's the thing about recursion - no loops allowed...

Comment: Then you should at least have a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the recursive code in a function (it can't really be considered recursive until it is), and return a recursive call to the function if you haven't reached your base case (`k == len(message) - 1`), incrementing `k` each time.

```
def find_adjacent(message, pairs, k):
  if k == len(message) - 1: #subtract one to avoid getting a string index out of range error
    return("Number of pairs:", pairs)
  else:
    return find_adjacent(message, pairs+1 if message[k]==message[k+1] else pairs, k+1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  message = "message" # change to input("Enter a message:\n")
  pairs = 0
  k = 0
  m, p = find_adjacent(message, pairs, k)
  print m, p
```

The above prints

```
Number of pairs: 1
```

If you fancy it a bit less compact and quite a bit more readable:

```
def find_adjacent(message, pairs, k):
  if k == len(message)-1:
    return("Number of pairs:", pairs)
  elif message[k] == message[k+1]:
    if k == 0:
      return find_adjacent(message, pairs+1, k+1) # first letter of message, all good
    elif message[k] != message[k-1]:
      return find_adjacent(message, pairs+1, k+1) # not first letter, and this pair hasn't been counted before
    else:
      return find_adjacent(message, pairs, k+1) # this sequence has already been counted
  else:
    return find_adjacent(message, pairs, k+1)
```

Comment: This is brilliant! However, if you wanted to remove the brackets and inverted commas from the output, what would you do?

Comment: @Lauren I updated the answer to print it the way you wanted. The function returns a tuple (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple). That `m, p = find_adjacent(message, pairs, k` syntax *unpacks* the tuple. By the way, those "inverted commas" as you call them are called single quotes :)

Comment: I'm having a slight problem - when I enter an input of "aaa" it says the number of pairs is 2, when the required output I'm meant to be getting is 1... So somehow after the pair is found, it needs to go to the end of the pair and start again... How do I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know you wanted longer sequences to only be counted as one pair. I've updated my last bit of code and added (hopefully) explanatory comments, do shout out if there's something unclear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive function that passes a new copy of the message, each time shorter.

This is what most recursive functions do: not memory-efficient but solving the problem in simpler ways than loop-based approaches. That's not the case here of course, but this is just an exercise.

```
def count_adj(message, adj, c):
    """Recursively counts the number of adjacent characters"""
    if len(message) < 1:
        return adj
    else:
        if c == message[0]:
            adj += 1
        return count_adj(message[1:], adj, message[0])


tests = ("Hello, Sabeeenaa", "Hi", "h", "HH", "HHH", "", " ", "  ")

for t in tests:
    print t, ":", count_adj(t, 0, '')
```

Results:

```
Hello, Sabeeenaa : 4
Hi : 0
h : 0
HH : 1
HHH : 2
 : 0
  : 0
   : 1
```